# How to transparently use the refresh token when connecting to Azure AD or AWS Cognito via OIDC?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito, openid-connect

The application I'm working on is composed by two sister web applications, each composed by a frontend Razor webapp and a Minimal API backend.
The first one uses Azure AD to authenticate corporate employees. The second uses an AWS Cognito user pool to authenticate customers.

Both webapps correctly establish the connection to their IdP and use the token to authenticate themselves to their respective backend app.

The problem I'm facing is that eventually the token expires and the authentication cookie is still valid so I see that I am still authenticated on the website but the token I forward to the backend is expired.

I want the system to use the `refresh_token` to automatically fetch a fresh token and I use the `CookieAuthenticationOptions` `OnValidatePrincipal` event to hook in my code.

Here is what I got so far:

How I set up the Authentication workflow:

```cs
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Events = new()
        {
            OnValidatePrincipal = OnValidatePrincipalAsync
        };
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
    {
        var azureAdOptions = new AzureAdOptions();
        builder.Configuration.GetSection("Authentication").Bind(azureAdOptions);
        builder.Configuration.GetSection("Authentication").Bind(options);
        
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
        
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.MapInboundClaims = false;

        options.TokenValidationParameters = new()
        {
            NameClaimType = "name"
        };
    });
```

The `OnValidatePrincipalAsync` method and its dependant

```cs
async Task OnValidatePrincipalAsync(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context)
{
    if (context.Principal?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false)
    {
        var idToken = context.Properties.GetTokenValue("id_token");
        var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(idToken);
        
        if (jwt.ValidTo.ToLocalTime() < DateTime.Now)
        {
            var refreshToken = context.Properties.GetTokenValue("refresh_token");

            if (refreshToken is null)
            {
                context.RejectPrincipal();

                return;
            }

            var tokenResponse = await GetFreshTokenAsync(context.HttpContext, refreshToken);

            if (tokenResponse is null)
            {
                context.RejectPrincipal();

                return;
            }

            var expirationValue = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().AddSeconds(tokenResponse.ExpiresIn).ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            context.Properties.UpdateTokenValue("refresh_token", tokenResponse.RefreshToken);
            context.Properties.UpdateTokenValue("id_token", tokenResponse.IdToken);
            context.Properties.UpdateTokenValue("access_token", tokenResponse.AccessToken);
            context.Properties.UpdateTokenValue("expires_at", expirationValue);

            context.ShouldRenew = true;
        }
    }
}

async Task<TokenResponse?> GetFreshTokenAsync(HttpContext httpContext, string refreshToken)
{
    var serviceProvider = httpContext.RequestServices;
    var cancellationToken = httpContext.RequestAborted;
    
    var oidcOptions = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptionsSnapshot<OpenIdConnectOptions>>().Get(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    var configuration = oidcOptions.Configuration ?? await oidcOptions.ConfigurationManager!.GetConfigurationAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    
    var httpClientFactory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();

    var address = configuration.TokenEndpoint;
    var clientId = oidcOptions.ClientId!;
    var clientSecret = oidcOptions.ClientSecret!;

    using var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

    var requestBody = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        ["grant_type"] = "refresh_token",
        ["client_id"] = clientId,
        ["refresh_token"] = refreshToken,
        ["scope"] = string.Join(" ", oidcOptions.Scope),
        ["client_secret"] = clientSecret
    };

    using var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, address);
    httpRequest.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(requestBody);

    using var httpResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest, cancellationToken);

    if (!httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return null;
    }
    
    var tokenResponse = await httpResponse.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<TokenResponse>(cancellationToken);

    return tokenResponse;
}
```

And finally, how I request the token when I need to call the backend:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient(AdminApiName, async (sp, http) =>
{
    var context = sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext!;

    var idToken = await context.GetTokenAsync("id_token");

    http.BaseAddress = configuration.GetServiceUri("admin-api");
    http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", idToken);
});
```

The `GetFreshTokenAsync` gets a fresh token but I am not able to use it to replace the old method, so when the controller/endpoint asks for a new HttpClient, the `context.GetTokenAsync("id_token")` call returns the old one. Since it expired, the backend returns a 401.

How do I solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the token is refreshed after the HttpClient has already acquired the old token, the HttpClient will not be aware of the refreshed token and will continue to use the stale one.

When you renew the token in `OnValidatePrincipalAsync`, you are correctly setting `context.ShouldRenew = true;` which should update the cookie with the new token information. Make sure this is happening before any HttpClient tries to use the tokens.

Here the code you could try:

```
services.AddHttpClient(AdminApiName, async (sp, http) =>
{
    var context = sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext!;
    var auth = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IAuthenticationService>();
    var authenticateResult = await auth.AuthenticateAsync(context, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    if (!authenticateResult.Succeeded)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Authentication failed.");
    }

    var idToken = authenticateResult.Properties.GetTokenValue("id_token");
    
    if (TokenNeedsRefresh(authenticateResult.Properties))
    {
        // Manually trigger the OnValidatePrincipalAsync event or abstract the refresh logic into a reusable method
        // You could trigger it by calling context.SignInAsync(authenticateResult.Principal, authenticateResult.Properties);
        // However, you may need to abstract the refresh token logic and call it directly here.
    }

    idToken = authenticateResult.Properties.GetTokenValue("id_token"); // Get the refreshed token

    http.BaseAddress = configuration.GetServiceUri("admin-api");
    http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", idToken);
});
```

After refreshing the tokens in `OnValidatePrincipalAsync`, make sure the authentication cookie is updated with the new token values:

```
    context.Properties.StoreTokens(new List<AuthenticationToken>
    {
        new AuthenticationToken { Name = "id_token", Value = tokenResponse.IdToken },
        new AuthenticationToken { Name = "access_token", Value = tokenResponse.AccessToken },
        new AuthenticationToken { Name = "refresh_token", Value = tokenResponse.RefreshToken }
    });

await context.HttpContext.SignInAsync(context.Principal, context.Properties);
```

Always check if the token is near expiration, not only if it has already expired, as it may expire while in transit or processing.

```
private bool TokenNeedsRefresh(AuthenticationProperties properties)
{
    var expirationValue = properties.GetTokenValue("expires_at");
    if (DateTime.TryParse(expirationValue, out var expiresAt))
    {
        return expiresAt.AddMinutes(-5) < DateTime.UtcNow; // Checking 5 minutes before actual expiration
    }
    return true;
}
```

Consider creating a service that manages the token lifecycle, so you have a single point of responsibility for acquiring and refreshing tokens. Inject this service into your HttpClient configuration delegate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will try your solution ASAP.

Regarding pinning the token in a HttpClient happening before, it is my understanding that the OnValidatePrincipal should happen before any non-auth code so I don't see a reason for it to happen.

Do you know if there is a difference between StoreTokens and UpdateTokenValue?

Comment: The `StoreTokens` method replaces the entire collection of tokens with the new ones provided. This can be a cleaner approach if you are setting all the tokens at once because it ensures there's no old or stale data left over. `UpdateTokenValue`, on the other hand, updates individual token values. @Kralizek